# Closed form of iterated integrals arising in Fredholm's integral equation solution in the context of non-equilibrium quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, greens-functions, non-equilibrium

While solving a non-equilibrium quantum field theory problem I came across this class of second-order iterated integral :

$$F(T_{}^{},T_{0}^{},\epsilon)=\int_{T_{0}^{}}^{T_{}^{}}dt_{1}^{}\cdots\int_{T_{0}^{}}^{T_{}^{}}dt_{2n}^{}\text{Tr}\left[\hat{A}_{1}^{1}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})\hat{T}_{12}^{}\hat{A}_{2}^{2}(t_{2}^{},t_{3}^{})\hat{T}_{21}^{}\cdots\hat{A}_{1}^{2n-1}(t_{2n-1}^{},t_{2n}^{})\hat{T}_{12}^{}\hat{A}_{2}^{2n}(t_{2n}^{},t_{1}^{} + \epsilon)\hat{T}_{21}^{}\right]$$

where $\hat{T}_{12}^{}$ and $\hat{T}_{21}^{}$ are $2 \times 2$  complex matrices and

$$A_{k}^{r}(t,t')=\Theta(t-t')\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}^{k}e_{}^{-ie_{r}^{}(t-t')} & a_{12}^{k}e_{}^{-ie_{r}^{}(t+t')}\\ a_{21}^{k}e_{}^{ie_{r}^{}(t+t')} & a_{22}^{k}e_{}^{ie_{r}^{}(t-t')}\end{pmatrix}+\Theta(t'-t)\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}^{k}e_{}^{-ie_{r}^{}(t-t')} & b_{12}^{k}e_{}^{-ie_{r}^{}(t+t')}\\ b_{21}^{k}e_{}^{ie_{r}^{}(t+t')} & b_{22}^{k}e_{}^{ie_{r}^{}(t-t')}\end{pmatrix}$$

for $k=1,2$ and $r=1,2,\cdots,2n$. Here $\Theta$ is a Heaviside step function.

Is there a trick to finding closed-form solutions for this class of integrals?

**My attempt:** I tried using Fourier representation: $A_{k}^{r}(t,t') \rightarrow A_{k}^{r}(E,E')$, using which I could do $t$ integrals easily, but then I am left with $\{E_{k}^{}\}$ iterated integrals which look as messy as the original integrand.